# $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\ln\cos2x}{\left(2^{x}-1\right)\left(\left(x+1\right)^{5}-\left(x-1\right)^{5}\right)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Could you help me to find the limit:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\ln\cos2x}{\left(2^{x}-1\right)\left(\left(x+1\right)^{5}-\left(x-1\right)^{5}\right)}$$

Comment: What did you try so far? How far did you get?

Comment: Use Binomal theorem for small $x$ , $(1+x)^n=1+nx$  , and $\cos 2x = 1-2 \sin^{2} x \approx 1-2x^2 $

Comment: @Mann, and then use L'Hopital's rule? Is that what you have in mind?

Comment: Not really l'hopital rule :)   

The limit boils down to, $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x}{2} \frac{\ln (1-2x^2)^\frac{1}{x^2}}{\frac{2^x-1}{x}}$ @AvaSkovko  , which is equal to $\frac{0 * e^{-2}}{2 * \ln 2}$ I bet you know what this is, I like first principles of limit :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a neighbourhood of the origin:
$$\log(\cos 2x)=\log(1-2\sin^2 x)=-2x^2+o(x^3),$$
$$2^x-1 = e^{x\log 2}-1 = x\log 2+o(x),$$
$$ (x+1)^5-(x-1)^5 = 2+o(x),$$
hence the limit is zero.

Comment: Hi, Jack ! You miss a minus sign in the first line.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: many thanks, now fixed.

Answer (score 3):

$$=\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\ln[1+(\cos2x-1)]}{\cos2x-1}\cdot-2\left[\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin x}x\right]^2\cdot\dfrac1{\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{2^x-1}x}\dfrac1{\lim_{x\to0}[(x+1)^5-(x-1)^5]}\cdot[\lim_{x\to0} x]$$

$$=1\cdot-2\cdot1^2\cdot\dfrac1{\ln2}\cdot\dfrac1{1^5-(-1)^5}\cdot0$$

as $$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^h-1}h=1\implies\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\ln(1+h)}h=1$$

Comment: Nice one! +1 :D